# Storing XML into Oracle Database

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

I'm using oracle 10gR2.

I have a use case where by a chunk load of data needs to be committed into database but they are VIEW as a whole.

Therefore I am thinking of creating an XML to hold all the data in a row.

Should I use CLOB or BLOB?

May I know for what row type should i use for storing XML and what are the stuff I need to look up for.

Noob here with storing XML into oracle DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use clob for store xml. Don't forget to determine the length as you need it, use string in the entity.

you can use XStream to change Object - xml - Object, [reference here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html). Example:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
String xml = xstream.toXML(Object yourView);
Object yourView = xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

Comment: at about using XML Type?

Comment: you can use XStream to store it as xml object, or you can serialize it and then save it as string [like in this link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31349&seqNum=3). XStream more simple though if you want to get it back as xml.

Answer (score 0):

I also think Clob is more appropriate in your situation. Below are snippets from working code:

Entity:

```
private String xml;
```

TABLE DDL (ORACLE):

```
XML CLOB,
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="xml" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="XML" length="999999" />
</property>
```